# WPF DataGrid with checkbox column and Button to validate all checked checkboxes

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

in a WPF Project i have a page with a dataGrid named CommDataGrid. It contains severals columns and a Checkbox Column two :

```html
 <DataGrid x:Name="CommDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ENTREE">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateEntree,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ARTICLE" Binding="{Binding article}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° PALETTE" Binding="{Binding numPal}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ADRESSE" Binding="{Binding picking}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PBRUT" Binding="{Binding SumPdsBrut}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="POIDS NET" Binding="{Binding SumPdsNet}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LOT" Binding="{Binding MinLot}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DATE CONGELATION">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinDatecong,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DLUO">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinDLUO,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="ChoixPalette_Ckb"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Path= id}">

                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The user can Check one or more CheckBoxes.
In this page i also have a Button. Here's what i want to achieve in the Click event of that Button :
For all the checked CheckBoxes, it get the value of the first column of the DataGrid (id) and then a code will be added to update a SQL DataBase :

```
 private void Valid_Checked_Palette_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)CommDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(CommDataGrid.SelectedIndex);
        CheckBox chk = CommDataGrid.Columns[10].GetCellContent(row).Parent as CheckBox;
        foreach(CheckBox c in CommDataGrid.Items)
        {
            if (chk.IsChecked==true)
            {
                object id = ((CheckBox)sender).CommandParameter;
                int _id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                Messages.InformationMessage($"You Checked {_id}");

                // Code will be added later...
            }
        }
    }
```

But of course this code is not working. Can someone get me into the wright direction please ??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to a `bool` property of your data object and iterate through the `DataGrid`'s `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChoixPalette_Ckb" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" ... />
```

---

```
private void Valid_Checked_Palette_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in CommDataGrid.Items.OfType<YourClass>())
    {
        if (item.IsChecked)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

The data object `YourClass` is the class where the `id`, `article`, `numPal`, ... properties are defined.